# Is saving session under the same name safe in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, session

I need to save payment data in DB. So one of the ways is to store the data into session and in saving part do the rest.

I save it like this:

```
$request->session()->put('paymentData', $request->all());
```

And then in another controller I call the same session, do some things and then remove the session:

```
    $data = $request->session()->get('paymentData', 'default');
    // do some DB storing
    // delete session
    $request->session()->forget('paymentData');
```

My question is, if two users are doing payments at same time. Can it happen that they mix these sessions because they will access it under the same name `paymentData`? Session will be stored in file in storage\session. Or Laravel have some method to distinguish these two Sessions even though they have the same name/key?

Comment: No. Session data at server is identified by a unique client id sent to / by every client ( user's browser ) as a cookie

Comment: I thought so but wasn't sure. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sessions are created per browser session. The Session instance is accessed by a specific session ID. The browser keeps the session ID in a cookie and sends it every time it makes a request, so the server knows which session to use for that request.

What you put *within* the session can be duplicated no problem - other users cannot see that data (unless they somehow obtain the session ID by a browser attack).